# To find the region of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to find the region of convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n!){z^{n^2}}$$

I am trying the ratio test but I am unable to find the limit obtained in the process.

Comment: The radius of convergence can be determined without the ratio test, and this general formula never fails like the ratio test.  Judging from the expression you have, you should have learned that formula at some point.  Googling the term "radius of convergence" should point you to the correct direction.

Comment: @Batominovski You mean $ R= \lim_{n \to \infty} sup (a_n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ ? That's applicable when the series is of the form $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_n}(z-z_o)^{n} $. Can I apply it here as well when there is a power on $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  And yes, you can apply it here.